# Finding two 'y' values corresponding to 1 'x' value in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following curve:

[image: curve with 2 y values for one x]

I am trying to retrieve the two y values that correspond to one x value (here 0).

I have tried `interp1d` from `scipy` but this only works with a monotonously increasing or decreasing curve. In the present case it finds the two closest values and does a linear interpolation between them and results in only one value located around 3.9.

Here is a code snippet to reproduce the example:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

testdata = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
testy = np.cos(testdata)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(testy, testdata)
ax.axvline(0, c = 'r')
f = interpolate.interp1d(testy, testdata)

print(f(0))
```

What could be a good way to retrieve those values ? I have also tried to get the closest value but this is not accurate enough for what I plan to use it for.

Thanks for your help

**Edit:**

The following solution works but is there a better way to do it ?

```
testdata = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
testy = np.cos(testdata)

gradx = np.gradient(testy)
asign = np.sign(gradx)
signchange = ((np.roll(asign, 1) - asign) != 0).astype(int)
splitloc = [i for i, e in enumerate(signchange) if e != 0]
newdata = np.split(testy,splitloc)
newx = np.split(testdata,splitloc)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(splitloc)):
    ax.plot(newdata[i+1], newx[i+1])
    f = interpolate.interp1d(newdata[i+1], newx[i+1])
    print(f(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method you could try is to break the input apart into chunks that are near your desired x-value (I renamed your variables to be closer to what they are in your plots):

```
test_y = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
test_x = np.cos(test_y)
# Determine which parts are close to zero
close_to_zero = np.isclose(test_x, 0, atol=1e-1)
```

Now we can break your input up into "continuous" chunks that are close to zero:

```
chunks = []
prev_close = False
for x, y, close in zip(test_x, test_y, close_to_zero):
    if not close:
        if prev_close:
            chunks.append(chunk)
    if close:
        if not prev_close:
            chunk=[[y], [x]]
        chunk[0].append(y)
        chunk[1].append(x)
    prev_close = close
chunks
```

Output:

```
[[[1.5231964381041423,
   1.5231964381041423,
   1.5866629563584815,
   1.6501294746128208],
  [0.04758191582374218,
   0.04758191582374218,
   -0.01586596383480803,
   -0.07924995685678855]],
 [[4.6330558325667655,
   4.6330558325667655,
   4.696522350821105,
   4.759988869075444],
  [-0.07924995685678878,
   -0.07924995685678878,
   -0.01586596383480761,
   0.04758191582374238]]]
```

You can now iterate over the `(y, x)` list pairs in `chunks`, and do a linear interpolation on those pairs to get a more exact value.

Answer (score 0):

As the data that you're trying to interpolate is not a function, i think it will be hard to solve your problem by interpolation. But you can see that if you multiply consecutive values over x, the sign off all the values will be (+) except on the nearest points where x=0 there will be a sign change (-). By using:

```
vals=[testdata[j] for j in range(len(testy)-1) if np.sign(testy[j]*testy[j+1])==-1]
```

I get `[1.5231964381041423, 4.696522350821105]`. You can use either `j`or `j+1` over `testdata[j]`as the grid is uniform both approximations will have the same amount of error. Hope it helps.